# Slow TTFB hosted application

Tags: performance, http, time, server

> Specifications

Hi,

I have an application hosted on a Linux Server.

The Server's hardware specifications are very good (10Gbit/s network card capacity, 15 CPUs (Xeon), +64GB RAM, 10G fiber network).

The Frontend is written in Angular and the Backend uses Python and Elasticsearch as the database.

> Problem

The HTTP POST request takes less than 1s when tested on localhost.

The same HTTP request takes 5s when calling from the deployed application using the browser.

> What I've already tested

To make sure the problem is not in the Frontend part, I tested the call using Postman and cURL, both taking 5s. When testing from the browser, the 5s are assigned to the waiting time (TTFB).

To make sure the problem is not the Elasticsearch query, I also explicitely tested the call, taking only 1s. So the 4 extra seconds are still a mistery to me.

Where should I look to improve the TTFB?

I am 90% sure that the problem is not the Frontend part, but the fact the application is now on the Internet. However, given that the server's specifications are very good, I don't know where the issue might come from.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the server that is being used to host the application? What does the access log say? What is your architecture comprise of apart from this Linux server? High TTFB points to issue with server response time. It is not on the client side. Hence would require more inputs to narrow down the root cause. Also compare the response time from access log with TTFB. These should be close enough. If not, network is your bottleneck and it is constrained by client's ability to receive and not by the server's ability to send

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I don't have such details. Apart from the hardware specifications, I also know that the server is being hold in the Data Center of Politehnica University of Bucharest. I can access the server using a SSH connection and use some terminal commands to find out more about the hardware.